# Orthogonal complement to subspace of $n \times n$ matrices with trace = $0$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

For an inner product space $$W = \{A \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid tr(A)=0\}$$ with inner product $$\langle A,B\rangle:=tr(A^TB)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}b_{ij}$$ find $W^{\perp}$.

I know that $$\dim(W) = n^2 -1$$ and that $$W \oplus W^{\perp} = M$$

But I'm not sure of how to proceed. Would you be able to point me in the right direction? Many thanks!

Comment: 1) Have you figured out the dimension of $W^\perp$? 2) What is the inner product you are working with?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, Thanks for your comment. Finding the dimension of $W^{\perp}$ does seem like the right place to start, but I'm not sure of how to do so. This idea seems problematic, but might it come from $dim(W) + dim(W^{\perp}) = dim(M)$? The inner product we've got is positive definite, $\langle , \rangle$.

Comment: I mean, I can guess that you could use the inner product
$$\langle A,B\rangle=tr(AB^T)=\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}b_{ij},$$ but you might use another, so we need to know.

Comment: Ok. So, do you remember what happens to the dimension in a direct sum? IOW, how do you get $\dim (U\oplus V)$ in terms of $\dim U$ and $\dim V$?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Hmm, is it not simply $dim(U) + dim(V) = dim(U \oplus V)$? If so, then wouldn't that mean $dim(W^{\perp}) = 1$? That seems so bizarre.

Comment: I think the OP is confused in this question: if you write $\;W^\perp\;$ you mean the *orthogonal complement* of the subspace $\;W\;$ . For that you **must** give an inner product defined on your vector space, like the one Jyrki showed above, say (that's one of the most useal in that space). Otherwise you only want *a complement* to $\;W\;$ , which is another thing.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you, both. It looks like the inner product we have is very close to the one that Jyrki wrote above. $\langle A, B \rangle = tr(A^{T}B)$

Comment: Correct, $\dim W^\perp=1$. Now, can you think of a matrix $A$ that satisfies $tr(A^TB)=0$ whenever $tr(B)=0$? After all, this is what you need for $A$ to belong to $W^\perp$.

Comment: A non-zero matrix, that is...

Comment: A physicist would say this is obvious because for any matrix $A$, $$A=[A-n^{-1}\mathrm{tr}(A)I]+n^{-1}\mathrm{tr}(A)I.$$ The first matrix is trace-free and the second isn't, so there you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alright! So, I think I have the answer to this problem.

**WARNING: I'm a novice (and the OP), so the following may not be foolproof.**

### Some Explanation

As stated above, $\dim(W) = n^2 -1$ because $W$ is all the square matrices whose trace is equal to zero. For this to be true, we just need one entry along the diagonal of any matrix $A \in W$ to be such that it "cancels out" all the other entries combined (i.e. there needs to exists some $a_{kk}$ along the diagonal of all $A$ such that $-a_{kk} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{ii}$). Because all the other entries can be chosen arbitrarily, there is all but one "degree of freedom" for the entries of any $A$.

Also, it is frequently proven elsewhere that for any vector space $V$, the direct sum of any subspace $S$ of $V$ and the orthogonal complement of that subspace $S^\perp$, is the vector space $V$ itself. Therefore, $\dim(V) = \dim(S) + \dim(S^\perp)$. (Please correct me if I'm forgetting some conditions here.)

Using all this information, we know that whatever our $W^\perp$ will be, its dimension $\dim(W^\perp)$ will come from $\dim(M) = \dim(W) + \dim(W^\perp)$.

### The Answer

Looking at the definition of the inner product we have in this space, we know that for any $A \in W$ and any $C \in W^\perp$, $\langle A,C\rangle = tr(A^TC) = 0$, since $tr(A) = 0 = tr(A^T)$. Again, the entries along the diagonal of $A$ and $A^T$ are the same.

This leads to the idea that we need some $C$ which allows $tr(AC) = tr(A)$. Obviously, such a $C$ is the identity matrix, $I_{n \times n}$, which also has $\dim(C) = 1$. Therefore, $W^\perp = \lbrace C \in M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) \mid C = I_{n \times n} \rbrace$.

Comment: How do you conclude that $C$ is an identity matrix?

Comment: @Unknownx I believe that came from the observation that $C$ is the only matrix that satisfies $$tr(AC) = tr(A)$$ or, for elements $a_{ij}$ of $A$ and $c_{ij}$ of $C$: $$\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}c_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}.$$

Comment: Just to round up your answer (which I will upvote), observe that the correct answer is no just the identity matrix, but its span. What you posted is just one point, that is not a subspace.

Comment: What would the basis of $W^\bot$ be?